# Why is this happen?Explain each outcome

Tags: java

[enter link description here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/12types/index.php#1.2.1)
package One;

public class Quadratic {

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    int a = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(a + 1);//-2147483648
    System.out.println(2 - a);//-2147483645
    System.out.println(-2 - a);//2147483647
    System.out.println(2 * a);//-2
    System.out.println(4 * a);//-4
    System.out.println(6 * a);//-6
    System.out.println(8 * a);//-8
    System.out.println(10 * a);//-10
    System.out.println(3 * a);//2147483645
    System.out.println(5 * a);//2147483643
    System.out.println(7 * a);//2147483641
    System.out.println(9 * a);//2147483639

}
```

}
//these outcoms are confused me

Comment: Search about integer overflow.

Comment: Imagine it like the numbers are in a circle, and after Integer.MAX_VALUE the next number on the circle is Integer.MIN_VALUE. So overflow (and underflow) is happening when you "pass" that point

Comment: Work out each calculation as a `long` and cast to an `int`

Comment: Thanks a lot. it helps.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is Integer overflow and underflow. Integer.MAX_VALUE (2147483647) is the maximum number you can store in a 32bit value. So incrementing that means it overflows (rolls over) and becomes the Integer.MIN_VALUE (-2147483648). Same with decrementing Integer.MIN_VALUE which will then become Integer.MAX_VALUE. With multiplication the same thing is happening.